# Blender 3.+ mesh sequence import

Tags: blender

Is there any way to edit the mesh imported as 'mesh sequence' other than parenting the object to an empty and transforming that (so it limited to a transform of the whole object rather than the mesh itself)? I know I can use an add-on to change frames to individual shape keys but that is crazy for an animated sequence..esp. since the mesh in the sequence changes the amount of its vertices (I am importing a sequence of .objs from "Ready" reaction-diffusion simulator)
any tips/suggestions welcome!